# How to run prisma migrations when creating a docker container file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, prisma, next.js13

I have a nextjs app that uses prisma with a mysql database. I can succesfully create the containers and get the app working, but i must go in the docker terminal and manually run

```
npx prisma migrate dev
```

.If i don't, they give me error because the tables don't exist in the database. How can i run this command automatically when i run docker-compose up --build -d ?

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:18

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install gnupg wget -y && \
    wget --quiet --output-document=- https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | gpg --dearmor > /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/google-archive.gpg && \
    sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install google-chrome-stable -y --no-install-recommends && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /app


COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .


RUN npm run build


RUN npx prisma generate



EXPOSE 3000


CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]

#RUN npx prisma migrate dev
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `docker-entrypoint.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Apply migrations
npx prisma migrate dev

exec "$@"
```

To use [`ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/dockerfile/#entrypoint) in your Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:18
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install gnupg wget -y && \
    wget --quiet --output-document=- https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | gpg --dearmor > /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/google-archive.gpg && \
    sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install google-chrome-stable -y --no-install-recommends && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
RUN npx prisma generate
EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]

COPY ./docker-entrypoint.sh /docker-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

Comment: Consider making the last command in the entrypoint wrapper script `exec "$@"`, and adding back a default Dockerfile `CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]` as in the original question.  If you need to have the container do something else, `docker-compose run myapp bash`, it will still run migrations before running the alternate command.